# Alert function call several time after fourth click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.a').click(function(){
    another();
  })
});
function another(){
  alert('Now Click B');
  $('.b').click(function(){
    alert('B Clicked');
  })
}

<p class="a">Click A First</p>
<p class="b">Click B</p>
```

First Time:
after (Click A) "Now Click B" alert one time.
after (Click B) "B Clicked" alert one time.

Second Time:
after (Click A) "Now Click B" alert one time.
after (Click B) "B Clicked" alert two times.

Why?

Comment: Every time you click...event is being attached...

Comment: Because on every click of a "Click event" on b is registered.,  May i know what your expected output is ?

Comment: any suggestion @RayonDabre ???

Comment: Refer answer provided by __gurvinder372__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> after (Click B) "B Clicked" alert two times.

because everytime you click on `A`, you bind another event handler to B.

So, second time there were two click event handlers to B.

Make it (made changes as per Rayon's suggestion)

```
function another(){
  alert('Now Click B');
  $('.b').one("click",function(){
    alert('B Clicked');
  })
}
```

If there is no restriction on when the event on B has to be binded then assign the events in the `document.ready` event itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.a').click(function(){
    another();
  })
  $('.b').click(function(){
    alert('B Clicked');
  })
});
```

Comment: Why not: `$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.a').click(function() {
        alert('A Clicked');
      });
      $('.b').click(function() {
        alert('B Clicked');
      })
    });`

Comment: @RayonDabre I assumed that OP want to bind an event to B only after A has been clicked. Will suggest this also anyways. Thanks

Comment: Instead of unbinding and binding the event, we can just use a flag and bind event once,

Comment: @NischalKumarBC Then we will need to store the flag somewhere. Also, not sure why OP is doing this so trying to keep the code flag-less :)

Comment: @gurvinder372, I guess I read it wrong...OP is looking for conditional event binding I guess....

Comment: @gurvinder372, You could use `.one` => `$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.a').click(function() {
    alert('A Clicked');
    another();
  });
  function another() {
    alert('Now Click B');
    $('.b').one('click',function() {
      alert('B Clicked');
    })
  }
});`

Comment: @RayonDabre that is a good idea, better than unbinding and binding, didn't thought about this. Made the changes accordingly

Comment: @ARNAB what issue has come?

Comment: Now another issue has come.

`$(document).ready(function(){`
      `$(".a").click(function(){`
        `var a = (function(){`
          `alert(a);  // Line No: 4` 
        `},another());`
      `});`
    `});`
    `function another(){`
      `alert('Now Click B'); // Alert 1`
      `$(".b").unbind('click');`
      `var r = 0;`
      `$(".b").click(function(){`
        `alert('B Clicked'); // Alert 2`
        `return r;`
      `});`
    `}`

    `<p class="a">Click A First</p>`
    `<p class="b">Click B</p>`

Alert 1 and Alert 2 work properly but<br>
Line No: 4 does not work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: @ARNAB it is difficult to read it, can you share a fiddle or raise a new question?

Comment: @gurvinder372 here is the new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654520/alert-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Because you add new subscription on click ... After first click you add to button B event, then you add another event after second click

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, there are **2 onClick event handlers** for `B` after the **2nd** click of `A`. So you receive 2 alerts.

To verify, just do the **3rd click** for `A`, you will receive **3 alerts** when clicking on `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the `click` event is registered one extra time since event handler registration is inside the `A`'s click handler.

you can use jquery `.one()`,which attaches the event handler only once to the specified element.

> *Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.*

[jQuery API .one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

**JS CODE:**

```
function another(){
   alert('Now Click B');
   $('.b').one('click',function(){
      alert('B Clicked');
   });
}
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/fLmd83wm/1/)