# alert() does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a").click(function(){
    var a = (function(){
      alert(a);  // Line No: 4 
    },another());
  });
});
function another(){
  alert('Now Click B'); // Alert 1
  $(".b").unbind('click');
  var r = 0;
  $(".b").click(function(){
    alert('B Clicked'); // Alert 2
    return r;
  });
}

<p class="a">Click A First</p>
<p class="b">Click B</p>
```

Alert 1 and Alert 2 work properly but
Line No: 4 does not work.

Any suggestion ???

Comment: This is completely horrible way to do this. First of all for debugging use console.log(); Then go back to the drawingboard and re-do the coding.

Answer (score 0):

> Line No: 4 does not work.

It doesn't work since the function is not invoked after defining, check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/4nghL78b/)

Try this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".a").click(function(){
    var a = (function(){
      alert(1);  // Line No: 4 
      another(); //observe that this line is not in the initialization here
    })(); 
  });
});
```

Comment: actually i want the value of r in line no 4 ... is it possible ?

Comment: @ARNAB didn't get you, `r` is not scoped in that method. `r` is not visible in line4. What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: Actually I want to return the value of r to the first scope ... that's all. @gurvinder372

Comment: Thank you for you time @gurvinder372 however plz see this jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/arnabmunshi/9aku55ap/2/

and want the incremented value of r in first scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke it:

```
   }(),another());
  //^-----here
```

Comment: look this jsfiddle.net/arnabmunshi/9aku55ap/2 ...  actually I want to  see the value of r++ in first scope like line no 4. Is it possible ? @jai

Comment: No! That isn't possible. Unless you use a global variable or pass that value in the iife and use that.